# php/sql how to return each row in database separately?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to return each row in my database as a separate array of information. At the moment I have only managed to return all rows in the database as a single array, but that is not what I want.
My current code to do that is:

```
$previous_info = array();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE id =$user_id_session";
            $records = mysql_query($sql); 
            while($trip=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
                $previous_info[] = $trip;   
            }

            print_r ($previous_info);
```

This will return all the information inside a single array, but I don't know how to separate the information for each row?

Comment: Maybe `$previous_info['name'] = $trip['name'];` ?

Comment: what do you actually want ?? Question is not so much clear.

Comment: "seperate the information for each row"  - separate in what way? How and in what format do you want to store/process/transmit the data?

Comment: Maybe... `foreach($previous_info as $row) {`? But then why not just process in the `while` each row's data is already present there..

Comment: seperate and display the information in each row on the page as seperate entitiys

Comment: Plese elaborate (a lot)  on "on the page as seperate entitiys".

Comment: so right now all the information retrieved from the database is displayed in a single long line on the page. if i do a foreach loop with a <br>, it will display every single field on a seperate line. What I need is to display each row, on a line, and each new row on a new line on my page

Comment: In that case you've probably placed the `echo '<br />';` at the wrong place. Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to print each row separately. In that case, there's no need to create a new array.

For example, let's consider the fields retrieved from database are "id", "name" and "date" fetched as $trip["id"], $trip["name"], $trip["date"] respectively.

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

    $previous_info = array();

    /* Other code */  

    while($trip=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
?>

/* In between the while braces, print each row. */

   <?php echo $trip['id'].','.$trip['name'].$trip['date']; ?>
   <br/>

<?php } ?>
```

Let's say you have 3 rows in database. It will output in this format:

```
1,Trip001,2016-03-21
2,Trip002,2016-03-21
3,Trip03,2016-03-21
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score 0):

```
        while($trip=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
            print_r($trip);   
        }
```

$trip is already an array representing one row, when you add it to $previous_info you are creating an array of arrays.